# XML: Get only some child nodes of a node

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I want to traverse the two sessions in the below xml as two seperate nodes:

abc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<resource>    
<session>
     <parameter name="QWS" value="N1"/> 
     <parameter name="AQC" value="Y2"/>
     <parameter name="VDF" value="301"/>
     <parameter name="VTT" value="X2"/>
     <parameter name="HRR" value="Y2"/>
 </session>
 <session>
    <parameter name="ABC" value="N"/> 
     <parameter name="XYZ" value="Y"/>
     <parameter name="GHI" value="30"/>
     <parameter name="DEF" value="X"/>
     <parameter name="QQW" value="Y"/>  
    </session> 
</resource>
```

However when i run this code, it traverses through both sessions both times:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'E:/perl_files/abc.xml';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);

foreach my $session ($dom->findnodes('//session'))
{
    print "In SESSION \n";
    foreach my $parameter ($session->findnodes('//parameter')) {
        my $name= $parameter->getAttribute('name');
        my $value= $parameter->getAttribute('value');
        print "Tag in session is $name with value $value\n";
    }
    print "END OF SESSION\n";   
}
```

Leaving me with this output:

```
In SESSION
Tag in session is QWS with value N1
Tag in session is AQC with value Y2
Tag in session is VDF with value 301
Tag in session is VTT with value X2
Tag in session is HRR with value Y2
Tag in session is ABC with value N
Tag in session is XYZ with value Y
Tag in session is GHI with value 30
Tag in session is DEF with value X
Tag in session is QQW with value Y
END OF SESSION
In SESSION
Tag in session is QWS with value N1
Tag in session is AQC with value Y2
Tag in session is VDF with value 301
Tag in session is VTT with value X2
Tag in session is HRR with value Y2
Tag in session is ABC with value N
Tag in session is XYZ with value Y
Tag in session is GHI with value 30
Tag in session is DEF with value X
Tag in session is QQW with value Y
END OF SESSION
```

I would like the output to be

```
In SESSION
Tag in session is QWS with value N1
Tag in session is AQC with value Y2
Tag in session is VDF with value 301
Tag in session is VTT with value X2
Tag in session is HRR with value Y2
END OF SESSION
In SESSION
Tag in session is ABC with value N
Tag in session is XYZ with value Y
Tag in session is GHI with value 30
Tag in session is DEF with value X
Tag in session is QQW with value Y
END OF SESSION
```

I am using XML::LibXML.
What changes could I make to get the child nodes of only one session every time? 
I saw answers using childNodes(), but that would return a list and I do not want to use grep to find a particular node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```xml
//parameter
```

is short for

```xml
/descendant::parameter
```

which means a descendant of the root node (`/`) named `parameter`, but you want to get descendants of the context node. For that, you want

```xml
descendant::parameter
```

which can also be written as

```xml
.//parameter
```

The thing is, `parameter` is a child of sessions, so what you really want is just

```xml
child::parameter
```

which can also be written as

```xml
parameter
```

---

Final code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'E:/perl_files/abc.xml';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);

foreach my $session ($dom->findnodes('/resource/session'))         # <---
{
    print "In SESSION \n";
    foreach my $parameter ($session->findnodes('parameter')) {     # <---
        my $name= $parameter->getAttribute('name');
        my $value= $parameter->getAttribute('value');
        print "Tag in session is $name with value $value\n";
    }
    print "END OF SESSION\n";   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`//parameter` searches for `parameter` everywhere, you only need to search under `session`, i.e. under the current node:

```
    foreach my $parameter ($session->findnodes('.//parameter')) {
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!